# MySQL performance: join of two tables on common foreign key: still "using where"

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, database-performance, database-optimization

I have the following tables: `test_user`, `test_tag`, `product`, `productinfo` (`productinfo` has a foreign key to `product`).

In addition, I have tables that model some relationships between the previous tables: `test_usertagging` (FK to `test_tag` and to `test_user`), `productinfo_tags` (FK to `test_tag` and to `test_productinfo`).

(Below I attach a fuller description, but this is the main idea).

Now I have a list of product IDs and user IDs, and I want to find the tags in common between them, as well as an additional `extra_info` column from `test_usertagging`:

```
mysql> explain SELECT `test_usertagging`.`user_id`, `test_usertagging`.`tag_id`, `test_usertagging`.`extra_info`
       FROM `productinfo`
       INNER JOIN `productinfo_tags` ON ( `productinfo_tags`.`productinfo_id` = `productinfo`.`id` )
       INNER JOIN `test_tag` ON ( `test_tag`.`id` = `productinfo_tags`.`tag_id` )
       INNER JOIN `test_usertagging` ON ( `test_usertagging`.`tag_id` = `test_tag`.`id` )
    WHERE
       (`test_usertagging`.`user_id` IN (1,2,3,4 ... ) AND
        `productinfo`.`product_id` IN ('abc', 'def', '000', '111', ...));
```

The formatted query:

```
SELECT test_usertagging.user_id,
       test_usertagging.tag_id,
       test_usertagging.extra_info
  FROM productinfo
  JOIN productinfo_tags ON productinfo_tags.productinfo_id = productinfo.id
  JOIN test_tag ON test_tag.id = productinfo_tags.tag_id
  JOIN test_usertagging ON test_usertagging.tag_id = test_tag.id
 WHERE test_usertagging.user_id IN (1,2,3,4 ... )
   AND productinfo.product_id IN ('abc', 'def', '000', '111', ...)
```

What I get is:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---    -----------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type   | possible_keys                                                    | key                          | key_len | ref                                  | rows |     Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+---    -----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | productinfo      | range  | PRIMARY,productinfo_218f3960                                       | productinfo_218f3960      | 62      | NULL                                |   55 | Using     where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | productinfo_tags | ref    | productinfo_id,productinfo_tags_4b5946a2,productinfo_tags_5659cca2 | productinfo_id            | 4       | tookyo_prod.productinfo.id          |    1 | Using     index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_tag         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                            | PRIMARY                   | 4       | tookyo_prod.productinfo_tags.tag_id |    1 | Using     index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_usertagging | ref    | test_usertagging_5659cca2                                          | test_usertagging_5659cca2 | 4       | tookyo_prod.productinfo_tags.tag_id |  217 | Using where              |
+----+-------------+---------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

This query performs badly. What bothers me is the 'using where' (without index) for the last row (test_usertagging) - the right index is listed under `key`, but it still says 'using where'.

I've tried adding `FORCE INDEX`, but that didn't improve matters (since the right index is listed anyway).

Using `STRAIGHT JOIN` just changes the order between the last two rows. (Note that the `test_tag` table itself is redundant for this query; removing it altogether doesn't change anything).

Any idea about how to make the query from `test_usertagging` use either or both of the relevant usable indices (`user_id` or `tag_id`)?

Here's the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the connecting tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_usertagging` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `usertagging_user_per_tag_is_unique` (`user_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `test_usertagging_5659cca2` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `test_usertagging_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `test_tag` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `test_usertagging_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `test_user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6456921 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `productinfo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `inftype` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `extra_info` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `productinfo_218f3960` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_id_refs_rpk_d9184c73` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`rpk`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44088 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `productinfo_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `productinfo_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `productinfo_id` (`productinfo_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `productinfo_tags_4b5946a2` (`productinfo_id`),
  KEY `productinfo_tags_5659cca2` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `productinfo_id_refs_id_1c393f74` FOREIGN KEY (`productinfo_id`) REFERENCES `productinfo` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tag_id_refs_id_0afa07dc` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `test_tag` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62637 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: You missed one more table in SHOW CREATE TABLE. You are getting 'using where' because of `test_usertagging`.`user_id` IN (1,2,3,4 ... ). MySQL joins the table and then checks this condition to satisfy

Comment: If you recast `WHERE test_usertagging.user_id IN (1,2,3,4 ... )` as `WHERE test_usertagging.user_id BETWEEN 1 AND 19` or something like that, you'll make that search term sargeable.  Also, the row counts in your EXPLAIN output are not enormous. How many rows are in each table? What performance do you have? What performance do you require?

Comment: @SamIvichuk But can't it use the index on user_id to check less rows?

Comment: @OllieJones Unfortunately in reality these are arbitrary numbers (user IDs), not contiguous. The tables aren't small - they have 100,000s to millions of rows each. The row counts given here are a MySQL's estimation of matching rows. The queries take several minutes (e.g. 3 minutes). I expect the right implementation can nail them within seconds, I guess 20 seconds would be acceptable.

Comment: @AmichaiSchreiber In your query "INNER JOIN `test_usertagging` ON ( `test_usertagging`.`tag_id` = `test_tag`.`id` )" is a loop where mysql gets one row using index "tag_id", checks if user_id in this row IN (1,2,3,4), then goes to another row. You need to refactor query or schema for better performance. If I knew what you are trying to achieve I could help you

Comment: Is the query you have shown the whole thing? What is `test_usertagging.extra_info`? Are you trying to retrieve other columns besides what you have shown? Are there any other WHERE conditions, ORDER BY clauses, or LIMIT clauses? Everything matters when you're trying to optimize a query w/lots of JOINs and megarows of data.

Comment: as well as showing the missing table @OllieJones

Comment: I can't offer a clear suggestion without knowing about the columns and tables you haven't shown us. But you should try these two compound covering indexes on `test_usertagging`, one after the other: `(user_id, tag_id, extra_info)` and `(tag_id, user_id, extra_info)`. For what it's worth, MySQL is not great at figuring out how to use its indexes with `IN()` clauses.

Comment: yes, the left-most in the composites in `test_usertagging` are important as @OllieJones says. In theory, the mysql CBO should handle IN() optimization but little OP info on the `in` other than they are not contiguous. As far as we know it is a set of a gillion values

Answer (score 0):

In a typical many-to-many mapping table, such as `test_usertagging` and `productinfo_tags`, there is usually no need for `id AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.  Get rid of the column, and promote the composite `UNIQUE` key to be `PRIMARY KEY`.

That change may speed up one direction because doing a lookup via the PK is about twice as fast as doing it via a secondary key.

Your title talks about `FOREIGN KEY`, when in reality, it is the index(es) that matter.  (A FK will create an index if it does not already exist.)